# Vibrate only when I'm away

Tags: notifications, 7.0-nougat

Is there an option or app where I can set that my phone only vibrates for notificaciones if I haven't used my phone in the last 5 or 10 minutes, but if not just be silent.
I don't to miss my notifications but when I'm with the phone I don't want that it vibrates meaningless.
I'm running Nougat.

Comment: Based on what shall be decided whether you've used your device? I assume screen-on would be an acceptable indicator? Might need a little work on your end to set things up, but take a look at our [automation tag-wiki](/tags/automation/info): [tag:tasker] or [tag:macrodroid] should be capable of that. Raw concept: use a "timer". Whenever screen is turned on, have it turn off vibrate and reset the timer. When your 5/10 minutes are up, have it turn on vibrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comment made by @Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195176/vibrate-only-when-im-away#comment251261_195176) is correct; you can accomplish it with automation. I am using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) to demonstrate it.

**Assumptions:** The screen is off (when the screen is on, you are using the phone).

1. In the Trigger tab, in the Device Events section, select Notification, then Notification Received. Choose `Any Application`, on the next screen, click OK.
2. In the Action tab, in the MacroDroid Specific section, select "Wait Before Next Action", then set it to 5 minutes (or any appropriate time length).
3. In the Constraints tab, in the Device State section, select Device Locked/Unlocked, then choose Device Locked.
4. Give the macro a name and save it. It will look like the image below.

When the phone receives a notification from any app when the screen is off, it will wait for the amount of time set then vibrates.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score -1):

upto my knowledge, there is no app is available in the market.
It can be done by creating one application using Accelerometer sensor functionality, which was an inbuild sensor in many of our mobile phones.

Comment: How shall the accelerometer know whether the phone was **used?** All it can decide is whether it was moving.

Comment: accelerometer will get direction based on phone dimensions, for example if u keep your mobile phone in flat surface then the coordinates will be as x =0 , y =0, z =0. it indicates that mobile was in flat surface. Based on these coordinate values we can code the app with some thresold coordinate values we can enable the notifications as u said vibration or notification sound.. i hope this answer will help u to understand.

Comment: OK, imagine I'm sitting in a train and the device is laying on a desk in front of me. The accelerometer then will register movement (not only because the train is moving, but also because of the table "rocking slightly") – though I didn't use the device. So acceleration (alone) is insufficient (in fact, it's not even relevant, as my example shows).